# error when trying to copy files from one folder to another r

Tags: r, copy

I am trying to move files whose name starts with 'ml1' from one folder to another.
I have tried the code below but I get the error "Error in file.copy(files, to.dir) : more 'from' files than 'to' files". Can someone help me solve this?

```
numb = 'ml1'

from.dir <- "xx"

new_folder <- paste0("yy/", numb, '/')
to.dir   <- new_folder

pat_numb = paste0("^", numb)
files <- list.files(path = from.dir, pattern = pat_numb, full.names = TRUE, recursive = T)

file.copy(files, to.dir)
```

Comment: Did you have a look at this? https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/issues/136